# jwtauth in laravel webservice not working

Tags: laravel, api, web-services, authentication, jwt

i'm writing a webservice with laravel. i want to add JWT authentication to it.
my controllers for api are in the

> app\http\controllers\api\v1\AuthController.php

directory of project. my laravel project version is 5.7 . i used these commands to install and configure the package:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source
```

and then

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

and

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

finally i added the following to app\kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
....
'auth.jwt' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

];

since i'm using laravel 5.7 i didn't add anything to config/app.php file. now i want to use JWTAuth in my controllers and when i use JWTAuth like below:

> use JWTAuth;

an error cames up says: Undefined class JWTAuth...

i reinstalled it and did composer dum-autoload several times but didn't work. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

in the app.php config file, under the aliases array, you may want to add the JWTAuth facade.

```
'JWTAuth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth'
```

or

```
'JWTAuth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class
```

Comment: both sides of => must be in the single cottations? like this: 'JWTAuth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth' . right?

Comment: did you install jwt correctly ? ,try to uninstall and install it again https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation

Comment: yes. i did uninstall it and installing it again several times.

Comment: try include ( use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;)

Comment: if i use this code: 'use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth' in the controller it's ok but when i want to use something like JWTAuth::attempt(); it says nonstatic method attempt() should not be called statically.

Comment: with ( use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;) again it says: nonstatic method attempt() should not be called statically

Comment: wich jwt package version you are use ?

Comment: this is in my package.json: ("tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop")

Comment: uninstall dev-develop it will be contain some bugs and install the stable version :"require": {
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
}

Comment: its better uninstall dev-develop version completly then :run command (composer required  "tymon/jwt-auth")

Comment: you should confirm in composer file must install the stable version not 'dev-develop'

Comment: did that and then run ( php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider" ) to generate the jwt.php in config file but it didn't generated !!!!!

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"

Answer (score 0):

For versions less than 5.5, you are also required to set service provider and alias in `config/app.php` file.

```
'providers' => [
    ....
    Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,
    ....
],
'aliases' => [
    ....
    'JWTAuth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
    'JWTFactory' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory',
    ....
],
```

If you are using version 5.5 or above, laravel does it automatically using Package Auto-Discovery.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app\Http\Middleware\JwtMiddleware.php` instead of this

```
use JWTAuth;
```

use this

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
```

But ensure that you have already included this facade in your app.php file